# How can I run my test environment on an EC2 instance?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to be able to showcase new features in my application to my boss without having to push those changes to the production server.  My understanding is that most software companies have a production server and a test server for displaying and testing new features in a production like environment.  Right now we only have a production server and my test environment is just run on my local computer on localhost:3000.  Our application is built in React and our server is an EC2 instance from AWS.  I would like to know what the best way would be to setup another EC2 instance but be able to run the test environment instead of production.

I have looked online but haven't found anything related to my question, but maybe that's because I'm not sure how to word the question that I'm looking for.

I have a good understanding in how to create a new EC2 instance but just need help figuring out how I would get localhost:3000 to be run from that instance.  If anyone has had any experience in setting something like this up or has any references online that might point me in the right direction, that would be helpful. TIA!

Comment: What you're looking to do falls under a very broad topic called CI/CD (Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery) and there are a ton of ways to do it.  At the most basic, you spin up another instance that mirrors the configuration of your production server and you publish / deploy to that instead of production.

Comment: @squillman would I have to then create a duplicate git repo for that? Or can I use the same repo?  If I have to create a duplicate, then how would I push those changes from that one to the production repo?

Comment: No, you don't need a duplicate repository.  Often this is done by using different branches within the main repository.

Comment: @squillman  Ok, I think I know what you mean now.  So the production server would just be pulling from the master branch, and then the test server would be pulling from say the staging branch?

Comment: Yep, that way you can merge dev changes to that branch while leaving your master (production) branch untouched until the changes are approved / confirmed.  Here's a link that you might be interested in on setting up a CI/CD pipeline in AWS.  https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/set-up-ci-cd-pipeline/

Comment: @squillman awesome! Thanks for your advice.  Sorry, one more question.  Would we need to pay for a different domain just for the test server to run on, or is there a way that we can keep the same domain and have the test environment run on that domain?

Comment: You should be able to set it up as a different host or subdomain within your existing domain.

Comment: @squillman Thank you, I appreciate the advice.  This pretty much answers my question.

Comment: Great, good luck :)